# Get-Item behaving weird returns [PSCustomObject] instead of item but sometimes working fine as well

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am trying to get a media item using the below, most of the times it works perfectly fine for me, however sometimes the same Powershell returns [PSCustomObject], instead of the media item.

[image]

Sometimes it returns me the correct item and sometimes it returns me this Object which ultimately results in null item path. Please suggest here.

Comment: Is it possible that the item does not exist but SPE is just showing `[PSCustomObject]` instead of null?

Comment: I am having the same doubt, can anyone please suggest on this. Every time I get [PSCustomObject] I believe its not null, please suggest if my assumption is wrong here.

Comment: You could try `if($GetImage -eq $null { Write-Host "It's null!" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael said in its comment, the item may be null. I did a quick test locally and below is the result

I've used the Item Id of the default Home item and the result shows that the item is not null.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path master -ID "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"

if($item -ne $null){
    Write-Host "Item is not null"
}
else{
    
    Write-Host "Item null"
}
```

However, when I change the ID to something which does not exist, the result is still shown as `PSCustomObject` but it shows that the item is null.

So, you need to check for null on the variable `$GetImage`.

```
$GetImage= Get-Item -Path master: -ID $parsedID

if($GetImage -ne $null){
    # Process item here
}
else{
    Write-Host "Skipping item id $parsedID as it is null"
}
```